# Change graphic but keep properties

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there a way to change a graphic, but keep the properties across frames such as size and positioning, so that the new graphic does everything the same? That's pretty much all I can ask since I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Can you explain the larger concept, or provide some code? And when you say across frames, do you mean of the movieclip, or the stage itself? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Take a graphic and animate it. I want to keep all changes to it - position (x, y), size (height, width), etc. - and put a different graphic in its place. Example: Make a spinning red triangle. Change the graphic to a blue triangle and still spin. No, I'm not just changing colors or making that simple of an animation, but that's as basic of an example as I can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quite a few options, here are two:

1) transfer across all the properties you need to your new sprite/graphic
eg.

```
myNewSprite.x = myOldSprite.x;
myNewSprite.width = myOldSprite.width;
myNewSprite.height = myOldSprite.height;
myNewSprite.rotation = myOldSprite.rotation;
this.removeChild(myOldSprite);
this.addChild(myNewSprite);
```

2) keep your graphics within a containing sprite add instead of altering the graphics directly alter the containers properties.

```
myContainerSprite.rotation = 180;
myContainerSprite.x = 200;
myContainerSprite.removeChild(redTriangle);
myContainerSprite.addChild(blueTriangle);
```